# how can we calculate normal force or vertical component of propeller in an aircraft?

Tags: propeller, engine

when we calculate thrust of an propeller engine we also face to vertical component or normal force which change neutral point of an aircraft how can we calculate this force? thank you

Comment: There is an old [NACA report (NACA TN 2586)](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/tr/pdf/ADA380456.pdf) on this by John L. Crigler and Jean Gilman, called Propellers in Pitch and Yaw